# apache 2.4.7:enable DELETE http method

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache-2.4, http

I've tried to enable DELETE http method for educational scope but didn't reached the goal ... I've read a lot of documentation but don't understand where and do I must set it.

First of all where is the apache default http methods limit? with OPTIONS / HTTP1.0 I can see only OPTIONS GET HEAD AND POST as allowed methods, where is the limitation?

Answer (score 5):

Since the DELETE method is part of HTTP/**1.1** you won't find it as part of the supported methods with `OPTIONS / HTTP/1.0` ...

You have the [`Limit`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limit) directive that can allow/restrict certain HTTP options:

```c
<Directory /var/www/html>
    <Limit GET HEAD POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS>
          # Deprecated apache 2.2 syntax:
          # Order Allow,Deny
          # Allow from all
          # Apache > 2.4 requires:
          Require all granted
    </Limit>
</Directory>
```

But I'm not 100% certain that you need to explicitly allow DELETE at the Apache level, unless it was explicitly denied before.

As far as I know it is primarily that you need a script/application that actually *does something* with such a DELETE request.